# WCF service with multiple service contracts with duplicate method names in single wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

Continuing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411213/wcf-multiple-contracts-with-duplicate-method-names) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817498/wcf-class-implementing-two-operation-contracts-in-different-service-contracts-wi) questions.
I have two service contract with the same methods:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServices1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IServices2
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}
```

And service:

```
public class Service : IServices1, IServices2
{
    string IServices1.GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    string IServices2.GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

According to reasons beyond my control:

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817523/2936295) answer not for me, I need to keep the original names.
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418676/2936295) answer not for me, I need single wsdl file. If you use a different namespaces, when you try to open single wsdl from service main page (http://addresToService/Service.svc?singleWsdl) get the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: A single WSDL document could not be generated for this service. Multiple service contract namespaces were found (IServices1, IServices2). Ensure that all your service contracts have the same namespace.

- I need one service with several endpoints.
- I need service like [this](http://pastebin.com/277DFF7H) (preferably on WCF).

Summarizing, I need WCF service with multiple service contracts with duplicate method names in single wsdl. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: You cannot do it, because it's equivalent to overload a method, and it isn't allowed in wsdl.
See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276124/why-method-overloading-is-not-allowed-in-wcf  and here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-wsdl12-20020709/

Comment: @RicardoPontual How can I get the wsdl like [this](http://pastebin.com/277DFF7H) with WCF? In this wsdl `<portType name="RegistrationSoapPort">` have `<operation name="AcceptRequest" parameterOrder="RequestID">` and `<portType name="CertRequestSoapPort">` have `<operation name="AcceptRequest" parameterOrder="RequestID Request">` in one namespace.

Comment: I posted as an answer because it was a little long for a comment

Comment: You must configure both endpoints in your Web. config, then it can also display the SingleWsdl

Answer (score 1):

Generate your classes from the wsdl file.
Save the content of http://pastebin.com/277DFF7H in a file, like "service.wsdl". Don't forget that `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` tag must be at first like, first column.

Then run the **wsdl.exe** util from **Developer Command Prompt** , like this:

```
wsdl service.wsdl /out:service.cs
```

Now you have the contracts as wsdl requires, and you can do any changes you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Generated file contains description of access to the service described in the `service.wsdl` file. But I need the service with the same interface as that of service with `service.wsdl` description.

Comment: use the serviceinterface paramenter and you will have the interfaces instead classes: wsdl service.wsdl /out:service.cs /serverInterface