# How to get single wsdl file for a WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to generate a single wsdl file for a wcf service for which .net framework version is 4.7.2. I see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-new?redirectedfrom=MSDN) says it is supported by default in WCF 4.5 version. When I try to access ?singleWsdl of the service, it still throws an error "System.NotSupportedException: A single WSDL document could not be generated for this service. Multiple service contract namespaces were found".

Any idea why it does not work ? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did any of this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388676/wcf-service-with-multiple-service-contracts-with-duplicate-method-names-in-singl

Comment: Not really, I was trying WCFExtras from this link but could not get it working. It talks about adding WCFExtras to web.config. But I dont understand the third step though where it says we have to add behaviorConfiguration. Should it be added to WCF service web.config or WCF client web.config ?

Comment: http://www.andyfrench.info/2013/01/single-file-wsdl-generation-in-wcf.html

Comment: At present, the single WSDL file will be automatically generated after the WCF service is successfully created. It is possible that there is an error in your server code. Can you provide some configuration information about the service?